# No keyboard in lock screen

Tags: huawei

I really want to avoid factory resetting the phone since I know the password but just cant type it in.

Things I tried and failed:

- rebooting my phone
- adb since no usb debugging

Phone: Huawei Honor V10 on EMUI 9

Answer (score 0):

> Try to connect a simple USB keyboard (best no integrated USB hub, card reader, RGB lights,... ) via USB OTG adapter. Most phones support OTG which should allow you to enter the password/PIN

This works! Thanks!